# Scala App doesn't run, just finishes with exit code 0

Tags: scala

Full application below - why does this not run with the menu ready for user inputs? Simply returns "Process finished with exit code 0" - I am unsure what I am doing wrong here, the menu should be displayed ready for user input to then return the data from the specified file.

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure, Using}

case object MyApp5 {

  case class State(name    : String
                   ,code    : Int
                   ,parties : Array[(String,Int)])

val mapdata = readFile("filename.txt")

  def readFile(filename: String): Try[List[State]] = {
    val dataRE = "([^(]+) \\((\\d+)\\),(.+)".r
    val pVotes = "([^:]+):(\\d+)".r

    Using(io.Source.fromFile(filename)) {
      _.getLines()
        .toList
        .collect{ case dataRE(name, code, votes) =>
          State(name.trim
            ,code.toInt
            ,votes.split(",")
              .collect{case pVotes(p,v) => (p,v.toInt)})
        }
    }
  }
  class Menu(states: List[State]) {
    def apply(key: String): Boolean = {
      val (_, op, continue) = lookup(key)
      op()
      continue
    }
    private val lookup: Map[String,(String,()=>Unit,Boolean)] =
      Map("?"    -> ("show this menu", menu _, true)
        ,"menu" -> ("show this menu", menu _, true)
        ,"all"  -> ("display all voting data", all _, true)
        ,"st"   -> ("vote totals by state", stVotes _, true)
        ,"x"    -> ("exit", done _, false)
        ,"quit" -> ("exit", done _, false)
      ).withDefaultValue(("",unknown _, true))

    private def done(): Unit = println("bye")
    private def unknown(): Unit = println("unknown selection ('?' for main menu)")

    private def menu(): Unit =
      lookup.keys.toVector.sorted
        .map(k => s"$k\t: ${lookup(k)._1}")
        .foreach(println)

    private def all(): Unit =
      states.sortBy(_.name)     //alphabetical
        .foreach{ st =>
          println(st.name)  //state name
          st.parties
            .sortBy(-_._2)  //votes in decreasing order
            .map{case (p,v) => f"\t$p%-12s:$v%9d"}
            .foreach(println)
        }
    private def stVotes(): Unit =
      states.map(st => (st.name, st.parties.map(_._2).sum))
        .sortBy(-_._2)  //votes in decreasing order
        .map{case (state,total) => f"$state%-9s:$total%8d"}
        .foreach(println)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    args.headOption.map(readFile) match {
      case None =>
        println(s"usage: ${this.productPrefix} <data_file>")
      case Some(Failure(exc)) =>
        println(s"Error reading data file: $exc")
      case Some(Success(stateData)) =>
        val menu = new Menu(stateData)
        menu("menu")
        Iterator.continually(menu(io.StdIn.readLine(">> ").toLowerCase))
          .dropWhile(identity)
          .next()
    }
}
```

This is a copy and paste from my scala case object MyApp5 (with the exception of "filename.txt" where I have put the absolute path - what am I missing?

Comment: @jwvh your application, just cant get it running properly

Comment: Maybe try to minimize the code so you can clearly identify the problem. - But, I would guess that the problem is that there is not static main method that could be called.

Comment: I copied the posted code to a file and compiled it, `scalac so.scala`. I then invoked the program, `scala MyApp5`, and it spit out a handy usage string, `usage: MyApp5 <data_file>`. Following such sage advice I then invoked the program as directed, `scala MyApp5 ~/junk.txt`, and it worked! How are you invoking the program?

Comment: @jwvh was hoping to be able to have the file read by the application and upon running the menu would appear ready for user input - what can be changed for this to be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Hard-coding the data file into the program would be a very unfortunate design decision. That way you wouldn't be able to run the program on different data sets, e.g. the results from different elections.

But ... oh well.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  readFile("filename.txt") match {
    case Failure(exc) =>
      println(s"Error reading data file: $exc")
    case Success(stateData) =>
      val menu = new Menu(stateData)
      menu("menu")
      Iterator.continually(menu(io.StdIn.readLine(">> ").toLowerCase))
              .dropWhile(identity)
              .next()
  }
```

I really don't see any point or advantage in doing it this way.